# Using HASHBYTES on large XML sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the `SQL Broker` & `SQL CLR` to push large sets of `XML` out to my Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) for consumers to pick-up and process.  In an effort to "audit" OUTGOING XML (I match it) with with XML RECEIVED by the service bus (by saving both into a table).

Saving LARGE sets of XML is easy...no problems there.  But I am getting the following error when I use HASHBYTES on LARGE XML values:

- String or binary data would be truncated.

Oddly...

- Converting to VACHAR(MAX) isn't the issue
- Using HASHBYTES is what fails

**THE GOAL:**
I need to HASH the values or reduce them into a CHECKSUM so they can easily be validated.

**As such, how can I HASH or REDUCE these large XML values into a single (small) value that can be easily & visually validated?**

**SAMPLE TESTER:**
Inserting LARGE XML into this question would be too cumbersome, so I am including a mini-script which replicates the issue:

```
DECLARE @ContextCount INT = 1000;

----------------
---- Build the LARGE XML
----------------
DECLARE @Count INT = 1;
DECLARE @Xml NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<Contexts>';
WHILE (@Count <= @ContextCount)
BEGIN
    SET @Xml = @Xml + '<Context><Name>SomeTableName</Name><Key><SomeColumnName>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Count) + '</SomeColumnName></Key></Context>'
    SET @Count = @Count + 1
END
SET @Xml = @Xml + '</Contexts>'

----------------
---- Build the LARGE XML
----------------

-- THIS WORKS
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Xml)

-- THIS FAILS
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Xml));
```

Comment: Are you sure it fails? I just copy-pasted your code to SSMS and query, which is expected to fail, worked. And I think that hasihng algorithms will be no longer supported in future SQL Server versions. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx

Comment: Change the count to 1000...it will fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HASBYTE` accepts `VARCHAR` but not `VARCHAR(MAX)`, so it truncates data and truncation error may be raised. If your data is longer then 8000 bytes, you may need to create your own function, kind of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10132/has-somebody-got-a-function-that-will-extend-hashbytes-to-strings-of-arbitrary-l

Comment: For the record: I chose teh SQL CLR path.  Thanks.

Comment: Native support for longer since SQL2016: "For SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and earlier, allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes."